# Laravel 5.5 optional parameter in routing is not working

Tags: routes, lumen

**Route:**

```
$router->get('vehicle/{year}/{make}/{model}/{rating?}','VehicleController@vehicle');
```

**Controller action**

```
public function vehicle($year, $make, $model, $rating = false)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

**URL**
http://localhost:8080/vehicle/2010/Wapal/S2

**Error**

```
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
```

Things are very obvious, it is surely a bug in laravel core? Why getting this error?

Comment: try changing your route to

    Route::get('vehicle/{year}/{make}/{model}/{rating?}','VehicleController@vehicle');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to make it work with multi optional parameters, hope it will help.
Works with Lumen 5.6.

Example:

```
$app->get(
    'vehicle[/{optional_year}[/{optional_make}[/{optional_model[/{optional_rating}]]]]',
    ['middleware' => 'auth' , 'uses' => 'VehicleController@vehicle']
);
```

If you don't use any middleware, something like that should work:

```
$app->get(
    'vehicle[/{optional_year}[/{optional_make}[/{optional_model[/{optional_rating}]]]]',
    'VehicleController@vehicle'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with, should work

```
$router->get('vehicle/{year}/{make}/{model}[/{rating}]','VehicleController@vehicle');
```